# prompt a user for input during silent .msi install

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, sccm

We are trying to create a deployment of a software called lanschool to our organization, via SCCM 2012. It functions basically by having an admin account create a channel that client accounts connect to for monitoring. We're using our admins phone extensions as their channel numbers.

The issue here is that We'd like to create a silent deployment package for this software, but would need some way to create a prompt during the install so that the admin can input their extension. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you launch the MSI with a command line that includes the data? This is the standard method of passing in data during a silent install. The required input values are specified as properties that can be input by the user in UI mode or passed in during silent mode, something like:

msiexec /I [path to msi file] MYCHANNEL=12345

where MYCHANNEL is the name of the public property.

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is essentially what we ended up doing, I'll put the code below for future browsers :)

Answer (score 0):

A silent install with user input? Ok then :)

My initial reaction would be to try to do it with a custom action (a simple VB script for example). However something at the back of my mind (I don't have access to InstallShield right now to test this) is warning me that any attempt at interaction would not show and could either timeout or throw an error. Don't take my word for that though.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is writing a bat file that prompted the user for their extension, stored it in a variable, and then added that variable data to the specified registry key. Code below:

```
::create a prompt for extension input and store input in variable "channelNumber"
SET /P channelNumber=Please enter your phone extension, this will be used as your Lanschool channel:  
::shut down lanschool
TASKKILL /f /im teacher.exe
::write variable to reg key
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Lanschool\ /t REG_DWORD /v channel /d "%channelNumber%" /f
::start lanschool
PUSHD C:\program files (x86)\Lanschool
START Teacher.exe
EXIT
```